# Xcode errors with 2 duplicate symbols

Tags: c++, build, compiler-errors

I am still in the process of revising my program however the only issue I am receiving when trying to build is that 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x84_64. I have not had this issue in the past and I am running xcode 14.0.1 on Mac OSX monterey.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include "Linked.hpp"
using namespace std;
time_t t = time(0);
tm* now = localtime(&t);

int main(){
 
    LinkedList l;
    Node* head = nullptr;
    string line;
    unsigned int sys_time = 0;
    
    fstream  myfile ("myfile.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open()){
       cout << "ready to proceed..." << endl;
    }
    
    ofstream outputFile ("output.txt");
    if (outputFile.is_open()){
    cout << "ready to proceed.." << endl;
    }
    outputFile << "Job_ID " << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4) << "Priority_Value  " << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4) << "Arrival_Time" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4) << "  Processing_Time" << endl;
    
    while(!myfile.eof()){
        std::replace(line.begin(), line.end(), ',', ' ');
        
        stringstream ss(line);
        
        getline(myfile, line);
        string date;
        int job_ID;
        int priority_value;
        int arrival_time;
        int processing_time;
        ss >> job_ID;
        ss >> priority_value;
        ss >> arrival_time;
        ss >> processing_time;
        l.enqueue(&head,job_ID, priority_value,arrival_time,processing_time);
    }
   
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

`

```
#ifndef Linked_hpp
#define Linked_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
class Node {
public:
    Node *next;
    int jobID;
    int priority_num;
    int arrival_time;
    int priority_value;
    int wait_time;
    Node(int jd, int pv, int at, int wt);
   
};
class LinkedList{
  
  public:
    Node *head;
    static Node* firstNode(int jd, int pv, int at, int wt);
    static int peek(Node** head);
    static void enqueue(Node **head,int jd, int pv, int at, int wt);
    static void dequeue(Node **head);
    static int getLength(Node* head);
    static bool isEmpty(Node* head);
    static void display(Node* head);
    
    LinkedList();
};
   

#endif /* LinkedList_hpp */
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include "Linked.hpp"

time_t t = time(0);
tm* now = localtime(&t);

using namespace std;

Node::Node(int jd, int pv, int at, int wt){
    jobID = jd;
    priority_value = pv;
    arrival_time = at;
    wait_time = wt;
    next = nullptr;
}

Node* LinkedList::firstNode(int jd, int pv, int at, int wt){
        Node *newNode = new Node(jd, pv, at, wt);
        newNode->jobID = jd;
        newNode->priority_value = pv;
        newNode->arrival_time = at;
        newNode->wait_time = wt;
        return newNode;
}
LinkedList::LinkedList(){
    head = NULL;
}
 int LinkedList::peek(Node** head){
    return (*head)->jobID;
}

void LinkedList::dequeue(Node** head){
    Node* newNode = *head;
    (*head) = (*head)->next;
     free(newNode);
}

void LinkedList::enqueue(Node **head,int jd, int pv, int at, int wt){
    Node* startNode = (*head);
    Node* tempNode = firstNode(jd, pv, at, wt);
        
        //This if statement will assign the head node the first item that is inserted into the linked list in order to begin the queue
        if(head == NULL){
            Node* newNode = firstNode(jd, pv, at, wt);
        }
    // If the head node's priority is greater than the next node then they are swapped.
        else if((*head)->priority_value > pv){
            tempNode->next = *head;
            (*head) = tempNode;
            }

       else{
    // If the head node is not null and its priority is less than the current node's priority that was just passed through the function then the head node stays as the highest priority while the the node that was just passed into this function gets compared to other nodes in the list.
           while (startNode->next != NULL && startNode->next->priority_value < pv){
                    startNode = startNode->next;
                }
         
                // Either at the ends of the list
                // or at required position
                tempNode->next = startNode->next;
                startNode->next = tempNode;
           }
    }
    // This checks to see how many nodes are in the list and then returns that value
 int LinkedList::getLength(Node* head){
    Node *list = head;
        int count = 0;
    // the count variable is used to count the number of nodes while the while loop goes through each node in the list until it reaches the nullptr
        while(list){
            list = list->next;
            count += 1;
        }
        return count;
    }
    //This boolean function checks to see if the queue is empty and returns either true or false back to main
 bool LinkedList::isEmpty(Node* head){
        return head == nullptr;
    }
    //This function displays the job's id, date, and its level of priority in the queue
void LinkedList::display(Node* head){
        ofstream outputFile ("output.txt");
    Node* list = head;
        outputFile << "Job ID  " << setw(10) << "Arrival Time  " << setw(10) << "Priority ID  " << endl;
        while(list){
            if (head == nullptr){
                isEmpty(list);
            }
            else{
                outputFile << list->jobID << " " << setw(10) << (now->tm_year + 1900) << "-" << (now->tm_mon +1)  << "-" << now->tm_mday << setw(5) << list->priority_value << endl;
                list = list->next;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried going to the build settings to see if there was anything that wasn't set properly but all the settings are defaulted to C++.

Comment: You probably dont' need to include any headers in your Linked h file. Try moving any required headers to the Linked cpp file instead. Try that and if you still get errors please share the specific error(s).

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong. It would help if you told what the error actually said. It might not mean anything to you, but it probably would to the people who can answer your question. Seems obvious to me, you gave us ~100 lines of code but failed to quote the one line of the error message. Please update the question.

Comment: Which symbols are duplicated? Please include the exact error message. (This also helps the next person with the same question to find your post.)

Comment: It would also help if you could trim down your code to a [mre]. Probably could get rid of most of the lines that do not involve the symbols that were mentioned in the error messages (whatever they were).

Comment: Since this is my second time asking a question and first time showing code I will make sure to learn from my mistakes and minimize the code. As far as the error that I received all xcode gave me was  "2 duplicate symbols for architecture x84_64."

Comment: @LMac It really should tell you what the duplicate symbols were. I don't know XCode but maybe you were looking at a summary of the errors, not the actual errors. With some compilers the full error message shows up in a window called 'console output' or some such. Have a look around because obviously knowing what the duplicate symbols are would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK figured it out (would have been faster with the error message).

Here's the first cpp file

```
time_t t = time(0);
tm* now = localtime(&t);
```

and here's the second cpp file

```
time_t t = time(0);
tm* now = localtime(&t);
```

Both `t` and `now` are defined globally in both cpp files. So you get a duplicate symbol error.

Since you only seem to be using those variables in the second cpp file, just deleting them from the first should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you! That solved the issue that I was having. I really appreciate you going through my code. I know it was a lot.